# Integral of $x^2\ln(x^2)$ without Integration by parts

Tags: integration

How would one evaluate the integral $$\int x^2\ln(x^2)dx$$ without integration by parts but *with* the knowledge that $\int \ln x dx = x(\ln x - 1) + C$.

There doesn't seem to a direct substitution that helps. But I noticed that we can pull a 2 out of the natural log, giving integral of $2x^2\ln x$, and that the derivative of $x^2\ln x$ is $2x\ln x + x$, which prompted me to attempt to represent the original integrand as a linear combination of the given antiderivative of $\ln x$ and the derivative of our integrand. This yielded no results either however.

I'm fairly certain, given the problem set and order of introduction of topics in the textbook this problem came from that there is a fairly simple way to do this without IBP, but as of yet, it eludes me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recalling that $$k \log x = \log x^k,$$
this motivates us to ask how we can transform
$$x^2 \log x^2$$
into the form
$$kx^2 \log x^3$$
for some constant $k$.  That is to say, we have
$$x^2 \log x^2 = 2x^2 \log x = \frac{2}{3} \cdot 3 x^2 \log x = \frac{2}{3} x^2 \log x^3,$$
hence $k = \frac{2}{3}$, and it follows that
$$\int x^2 \log x^2 \, dx = \frac{2}{3} \int x^2 \log x^3 \, dx.$$
With the substitution $$u = x^3, \quad du = 3x^2 \, dx,$$
we obtain
$$\begin{align}
\int x^2 \log x^2 \, dx &= \frac{2}{9} \int 3x^2 \log x^3 \, dx \\
&= \frac{2}{9} \int \log u \, du \\
&= \frac{2}{9} u (-1 + \log u) + C \\
&= \frac{2}{9} x^3 (-1 + 3 \log x) + C.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track with changing the exponents in the logarithm - just in this case it's a different change that's useful.
The idea is that you want to choose a substitution such that the $x^2$ term is absorbed in the $du/dx$.

To this end, chose $u = x^3$, so that $du/dx = 3x^2$, and
$$
x^2 \log(x^2)
= \frac{1}{3}\frac{du}{dx} \log(u^{2/3})
= \frac{2}{9}\log (u)\cdot\frac{du}{dx}.
$$

From here you should be able to compute the indefinite integral directly.